# NETGEAR ReadyNAS Duo with DLink Dir-635. Slow read/write speed

Tags: nas, readynas

I bought NETGEAR ReadyNAS Duo and installed WD 2Tb HDD. It works fine, except of the read/write speed. I think this is due to the model of my wireless router. (I hate dlink)
The upload speed is around 2.8 MB/s, and it decreases from time to time to 1.7.
And watching movies is also a painful process, because often the picture gets stuck.
I use laptop as my primary computer, and operate with my NAS via wireless connection.

My router's spec says : 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n • 300Mbps

Why the speed is so slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I came to a conclusion that I need to replace my router. The slow r/w is caused by the router.